# Issue in turn.js page box-shadow and left-margin alignment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, turnjs

I am facing problem in page flip turn.js

- I set the box-shadow for both odd and even page, but odd pages box shadow is display at first execution. At the time of second time page flip box shadow is not visible. For even page not visible at any time.
- I have set the left-margin of the page but pages is not shifting any more.

`#flipbook{
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
    margin-left:100px;
}`

```
#flipbook .odd{
background:-webkit-gradient(linear, right top, left top, color-stop(0.95, #FFF), color-stop(1, #DADADA));
background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(right, #FFF 95%, #C4C4C4 100%);
background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(right, #FFF 95%, #C4C4C4 100%);
background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(right, #FFF 95%, #C4C4C4 100%);
background-image:-o-linear-gradient(right, #FFF 95%, #C4C4C4 100%);
background-image:linear-gradient(right, #FFF 95%, #C4C4C4 100%);
-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
-moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
-o-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
-ms-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px red;
}
```

Where I am doing wrong?
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaveld/A9a7E/8817/)